# VS Code - search only the current active git branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I use the search on VS Code, it searches all the git branches I have. Is there a way to only search the current active git branch?

Comment: Are you sure? It should only search the files currently in your working copy.

Answer (score 3):

The [VSCode search across file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files) allows you to quickly search over all files in the currently opened folder, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/editor/codebasics/search.png]

Only the file currently available in your workspace (which can be your Git cloned repository working tree) are searched.